# The difference in value types/pointer types in golang

Tags: go

```
type T struct {
    Name string
}
func (t T) M1 () {
    t.Name = "name1"
}
func (t *T) M2 () {
    t.Name = "name2"
}
type intf interface {
    M1()
    M2()
}
func main() {
    var t1 T = T{"t1"}
    t1.M1()
    t1.M2()
    var t2 intf = t1
    t2.M1()
    t2.M2()
}
```

Why when I use`var tf intf = &t1`, It's correct
But when I use`var tf intf = &t1`, It's not correct
Is there any difference in the two representations?

Comment: I suspect your "why x but not y" examples are mistyped, as they are both the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when I usevar tf intf = &t1, It's correct But when I usevar tf intf = &t1, it's not

Since in your example you are using `tf intf = t1` (and it does not compile), I think you probably meant:

> when I usevar tf intf = &t1, It's correct *But when I usevar tf intf = t1, it's not*

So the question here is why `&T{"t1"}` (pointer) fulfils the interface `intf` while `T{"t1"}` (value) does not.

In your example, the interface has two methods `M1` and `M2`.

Type T implements both methods **BUT**:

- M1 has `T` *value* as the receiver
- M2 has `T` *pointer* as the receiver

So why does the compiler consider a `T` pointer to have both methods implemented but considers that a `T` value does not?

Answer can be found here in the spec:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets

> The method set of any other type T consists of all methods declared with receiver type T. The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T).

The spec says that a `T` pointer has all methods defined with receivers `T` and `*T` (so both M1 and M2 in this case).

But a value of `T` only has the methods defined with receiver `T` (so only M1 in this case).

Since the interface has both methods, only the pointer can fulfil it.